# Python- How to check if program gets aborted by user while running?

Tags: python

If I am running a python program on linux terminal and i abort it manually by pressing ctrl+c, how can i make my program do something when this event occurs.

something like:

```
if sys.exit():
    print "you chose to end the program"
```

Comment: You have to use the `signal` module.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18115530/1688590 . Also note that checking `if sys.exit()` will immediatly shutdown your program.

Comment: @xbello since OP asks for exiting with `ctrl-C`, signal is not required. `KeyboardInterrupt` is sufficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can write a signal handling function

```
import signal,sys
def signal_handling(signum,frame):
    print "you chose to end the program"
    sys.exit()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal_handling)
while True:
    pass
```

pressing Ctrl+c sends a SIGINT interrupt which would output:

> you chose to end the program

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Not, sure. This seems to be a valid answer though people are used to using `KeyBoardInterrupt` Exception.

Comment: @Abhijit: I would argue that a well-setup signal handler is nicer than having to wrap your entire program in a `try/except`. I guess it depends on what should happen if the user chooses *not* to abort the program.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I have seen both styles but depends on your background. The Former is more Cish Style where SEH/C++ Exception handling was absent. The Later is more predominant in languages which supports exception handling. Only cases, which EH was not able to handle, single handlers were opted. So my take is its more to one's taste, style  and preference.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can use `KeyBoardInterrupt`, using a try-except block:

```
try:
    # some code here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "You exited
```

Try the following in your command line:

```
import time

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print "Hello"
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "No more Hellos"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [KeyboardInterrupt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) exception in Python.

You can put your code in a `try` block, catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception with `except` and let the user know that he has exited.