# Python - How do I catch clicking Windows' command prompt 'Close' button?

Tags: python

When the user clicks the 'X' in the top right of the terminal running the program, I want there to be a confirmation that they really want to exit the program.

So far, the most that I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114560/python-catch-ctrl-c-command-prompt-really-want-to-quit-y-n-resume-executi) but that only works with 'ctrl-c', not clicking the 'X'.
I've also found

```
def on_exit(sig, fun=None):
    print("I can't prevent the exit")

win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(on_exit, True)
```

Which would be perfect if it could prevent the exit.

Comment: @JohnHennig They already had that kind of choice, though, as long as their malware is not running in a terminal.

Comment: To OP: I think maybe the answer is "get a terminal with that feature". For example, the default terminal of Mac OS X asks "Do you want to terminate running processes in this window?" if there is a process running.

Comment: A terminal is just for input and output. It just so happens to have an `x` button to close it.

Comment: @GeeTransit Thanks, I'll edit my comment to be correct.

Comment: @ImperishableNight Thanks for the suggestion, but I am looking for a solution for Windows' command prompt. I'll update the question title to be more specific.